# How to extract columns from neste pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

I woluld like to extract multiple fields from nested column.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()

 

mydata =([[{'id': 1, 'name':'project a', 'tag':'gg'},{'id':2, 'name':'project b','tag':'gf'}],

        [{'id': 22, 'name':'project c', 'tag':'gc'},{'id':111, 'name':'project x','tag':'x'}],

        [{'id': 33, 'name':'project y','tag':'gg'},{'id':999, 'name':'project h','tag':'gg'}],

        [{'id': 44, 'name':'project w','tag':'gg'},{'id':754, 'name':'project z','tag':'ss'}]])

 

s = pd.Series(data=mydata, index=[0,1,2,3])
```

My wanted output is a new dataframe:

[image]

df["col1"]= s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try via `DataFrame()` ,`explode()` and `drop()` method:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(mydata).explode().tolist()).drop('tag',1)
```

output of `df`:

```
    id      name
0   1       project a
1   2       project b
2   22      project c
3   111     project x
4   33      project y
5   999     project h
6   44      project w
7   754     project z
```

Comment: Good to know about "explode", you can use series instead of df
`pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(mydata).explode().tolist())`

Comment: @RanCohen thnx for the suggestion ***:)***

Comment: @AnuragDabas can I use this on my dataframe column since I need to use dataframe and not mydata pandas series. This is just an example.

Comment: @DJdrava yes you can do this on any column inyour dataframe

Answer (score 0):

try `pd.json_normalize` with `pd.concat`

```
df = pd.concat([pd.json_normalize(item) for item in mydata])

print(df)

    id       name tag
0    1  project a  gg
1    2  project b  gf
0   22  project c  gc
1  111  project x   x
0   33  project y  gg
1  999  project h  gg
0   44  project w  gg
1  754  project z  ss
```

---

you can `.drop` your columns after if you don't want them, or just select your target columns and then pass them to a new variable.

```
df1 = df.drop('tag',1).copy()

df1 = df[['id','name']].copy()
```

Comment: I have an error module 'pandas' has no attribute 'json_normalize' and I need to do this on dataframe my code is just an example.

Comment: @DJdrava what version of pandas are you using?

Comment: I'm using 0.25.1 version.

Comment: @DJdrava then you should defo have it, the function was added to pandas in `versionadded:: 0.25.0` according to the source code on github.

Comment: I will check. Thx